# xbindkeys Paste Script is Failing to Work

Tags: xbindkeys, xsel

I'm trying to bind `control + i` to load the contents of `file.txt` to the clipboard (so that I can use `ctrl + v` to paste the contents of `file.txt` into windows like my browser).

The following command works perfectly if I manually type it into a bash terminal:

`xsel --clipboard < /home/paul/Dropbox/file.txt`

However, when I try to use xbindkeys to do it, it does not. This is what I have in my `xbindkeys` config:

```
"xsel --clipboard < /home/paul/Dropbox/file.txt"
   control + i
```

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The [xsel man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xsel) says it tests stdin/stdout to see if they are a terminal, and outputs the selection if stdout is not a terminal, so add the option `--input` to ensure it
sets the selection instead.